# Build failed when adding app to iphone device

Tags: iphone

I have created a application in iphone and i have provision certificate for testing it in iphone.I connected xcode 4 with iphone and i changed the iphone stimulator to my iphone.I run the xcode ,all the files are complied but last there shows a failed message.It is not given any error message.I build my app with ios4.3,but my iphone is ios4.1.Is this is the issue for the build error?.Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the console and see if any error message...Anyone can't help you with so less information..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra ok let me check.lotes of warning there,but it runs fine in simulator.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra there is no error displying in it,but 58 warnings there.but i works fine in stimulator,is there issue in ios 4.3 .my iphone is 4.1

Comment: Treat warnings like errors. They are there for a reason.

Comment: @sosborn Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.
Program ended with exit code: 0 .THIS IS WHAT I GET FROM THE CONSOL

Comment: That is the error. I am talking about the warnings when you compile. Fix those and you will probably fix your other problems.

Comment: @sosborn ok sir,i will chk it by tmro,becz my offic time over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,i didn't add the private key in keychain accesses,after adding the provision certificate to the device and addding key to the keychain solved my issue.
Thanks.